# How to get attribute value from JSON and write it in file in specific format using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules

I have a test.json file and It's in below format and I just want to get link value from that file:

**Input file from File System:**

```
{
    "5cacd1333105": {
        "type": "CORR-ID",
        "environment": "amazon",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "EC-6S0005704A8324S98020",
                "source": "amazonstage2ma_paymentapiplatserv#TOKEN",
                "flags": [
                    "FLAG_DYNAMIC_VALUE",
                    "FLAG_ID_LOOKUP_SUPPORTED"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "callSummary": [
            {
                "colo": "lvs",
                "pool": "slingshotrouter",
                "machine": "stage21007",
                "apiName": "GET",
                "status": "0",
                "duration": 13400.0,
                "calls": null,
                "hints": null,
                "msgTime": 1574314991130,
                "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-942342192424j2j234"
            },
            {
                "colo": "lvs",
                "pool": "slingshot",
                "machine": "stage21029",
                "apiName": "GET",
                "status": "0",
                "duration": 13368.0,
                "calls": null,
                "hints": null,
                "msgTime": 1574314991162,
                "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-12342342i842424j2j234"
            },


            {
                "colo": "lvs",
                "pool": "msmaster_userbridgedomainserv",
                "machine": "amazon1int-g_userbridgedomainserv_22",
                "apiName": "POST",
                "status": "0",
                "duration": 15.0,
                "calls": null,
                "hints": null,
                "msgTime": 1574315001625,
                "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-02341723424i842424j2j290"
            }

        ],
        "partial": false
    }
}
```

I wanna get the below details from above file:

```
    "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-942342192424j2j234"
    "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-12342342i842424j2j"
    "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-02341723424i842424"
```

I just want to write into test.js file as below format.

```
    module.exports = 
    {
       fileNames:[
        'https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-942342192424j2j234',
        'https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-12342342i842424j2j',
        'https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-02341723424i842424'
       ]
    }
```

I don't know how to get those details. Can someone please share me some input on this?

Comment: Access the value using dot/bracket notation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: You can also use `.map` on the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `5cacd1333105` is a dynamic key, so it might change, and there might be more than one random key like that, so you can use a `for... in` loop like this to loop each key (prop) in the object:

```
const d = require('./test.json');

for(let prop in d){
  console.log(d[prop])
}
```

Then you can see that the only relevant property is callSummary array because it contains the link data. Therefore you can loop the array to extract the link data.

```
for(let prop in d){
  const obj = d[prop];
  const links = obj.callSummary.map(({link}) => link);
  console.log(links);
}
```

The above uses destructuring inside a `.map` callback to extract the link string from the objects inside callSummary, returning an array of link strings in `links`.

However, we still need to take into account the general case of multiple links due to the outer `for... in` loop.

To combine the links into a single array, you can declare links outside the loops as an empty array, and just push to that array, like this:

```
const links = [];
for(let prop in d){
  const obj = d[prop];
  links.push(obj.callSummary.map(({link}) => link));
}
console.log(links);
```

Finally, you want to write that data into a file. You can use either `fs` or you could spawn / execute a command line program from within your node.js script. See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback on how to use `fs.writeFile` or use `child_process` e.g.

```
const d = require('./test.json');
const path = require('path');
const { spawn } = require( 'child_process' );
const links = [];
for(let prop in d){
  const obj = d[prop];
  links.push(obj.callSummary.map(({link}) => link));
}
const filename = `links-${Date.now()}.js`;
console.log(`Outputting links to ${filename}`);
const echo = spawn( 'echo', [ `
module.exports = 
    {
       fileNames:[
           ${JSON.stringify(links, false, 2)}
       ]
    }
`, '>', path.join(process.cwd(), filename) ] );
```

Note the use of backticks. (I didn't test that last bit, but it should work).

Answer (score 1):

You have not shared how you are acquiring this data, but since you added a tag for node.js, I am assuming you are doing this on the server side.

After you make sure the data you received is in JSON format (using JSON.parse) and it is valid, to get the specific fields you require, you can do the following:

```
let links = [];
let callSummary = json['5cacd1333105'].callSummary
for (let index = 0; index < callSummary.length; index++) {
   let call = callSummary[index];
   if (call && call.link) {
      links.push(call.link);
   }
}
```

After this, you will have al lthe links in the array links and you can do whatever you please with them.

Answer (score -1):

This code have a little risk, but it's work in your situation

```js
const data = {
    "5cacd1333105": {
        "type": "CORR-ID",
        "environment": "amazon",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "EC-6S0005704A8324S98020",
                "source": "amazonstage2ma_paymentapiplatserv#TOKEN",
                "flags": [
                    "FLAG_DYNAMIC_VALUE",
                    "FLAG_ID_LOOKUP_SUPPORTED"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "callSummary": [
            {
                "colo": "lvs",
                "pool": "slingshotrouter",
                "machine": "stage21007",
                "apiName": "GET",
                "status": "0",
                "duration": 13400.0,
                "calls": null,
                "hints": null,
                "msgTime": 1574314991130,
                "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-942342192424j2j234"
            },
            {
                "colo": "lvs",
                "pool": "slingshot",
                "machine": "stage21029",
                "apiName": "GET",
                "status": "0",
                "duration": 13368.0,
                "calls": null,
                "hints": null,
                "msgTime": 1574314991162,
                "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-12342342i842424j2j234"
            },


            {
                "colo": "lvs",
                "pool": "msmaster_userbridgedomainserv",
                "machine": "amazon1int-g_userbridgedomainserv_22",
                "apiName": "POST",
                "status": "0",
                "duration": 15.0,
                "calls": null,
                "hints": null,
                "msgTime": 1574315001625,
                "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-02341723424i842424j2j290"
            }

        ],
        "partial": false
    }
};

const jsonDAta = JSON.stringify(data,null,null);

const resArr = (jsonDAta.match(/"link":"[^"]+"/g)||[]).map(el=>JSON.parse(`{${el||''}}`).link)

console.log(resArr);
```

Comment: I'm getting error message    const resArr = jsonDAta.match(/"link":"[^"]+"/g).map(el=>JSON.parse(`{${el}}`).link)
                                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:777:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan i added `null` arguments in `stringify`, maybe now all will work good, i checked this code in browser console and in snippet. All good